# Liste de valeurs/Liste des valeurs/Liste de valeur

Tags: grammaire, prépositions, pluriel, de

I tend to have problems getting it right with “de”.

To my knowledge, one uses “beaucoup de + nom (singulier)”.

But some other cases confuse me. For example

> Liste de valeurs/Liste des valeurs/Liste de valeur

Which one is correct and what is the grammar rule?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All forms can be used with different meanings.

*Liste de valeurs* : The list contains values.

*Liste des valeurs* : The list contains "the" values (*des* is a contraction of *de* + *les* here).

*Liste de valeur* : The list itself is valuable, probably not what you mean.

Comment: Thank @jilliagre. What is the difference in meaning between your first two explanations. I understand you meant _Liste [de les] valeurs_ for the second phrase. Btw, that's interesting the last phrase's meaning. I learn something new.

Comment: @Kenny In the first exemple, you are talking about the list (which contains values). In the second, you are talking about the values (which are in the list).

Comment: Can you elaborate ? In which scenario would we talk about the values. For your first meaning (talking about the list) I suppose when we talk about"Let's look at this list of values", "I'll give you a list of values" ?

Comment: @Kenny « Voici la liste des valeurs demandées » (you asked for some values, that you gathered in a list), or « Voici la liste de valeurs demandée » (you asked for a list made of values). Note that in the first sentence, "demandées" takes an "s", and the the second, it doesn't. It shows that the subject is not the same.

Comment: Nice explanation. Thank you Random